# Is anyone else seeing DNS problems with meta.stackoverflow.com just now?

Tags: bug, status-completed, dns

It looks like meta.stackover.com is hiding again:

[alt text http://www.zygonia.net/content/binary/JustPing-09-09-05.jpg](http://www.zygonia.net/content/binary/JustPing-09-09-05.jpg)

The UK test shows as ok but my ISP's DNS is reporting not found. In the meantime I've nailed the MSO IP address into my HOSTS file.

Comment: marking as `status-completed` in hopes that the new DNS servers are more reliable: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/new-dns-provider/

Comment: Cool by me.

Comment: Looks like an oversight during the data centre move:

http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164447/184438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no repro

http://just-ping.com/index.php?vh=meta.stackoverflow.com&c=&s=ping!

or maybe it was some temporary thing.

Comment: Lasted for around 30 minutes then started behaving again.

Answer (score 1):

I had to put the IP address into my hosts file a while back.

Comment: I periodically would have the issue as well until I also put the IP address into my hosts file.