# DNS server failure for all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, dns

It appears the nameservers for Stack Exchange are returning SERVFAIL for all queries, meaning most users are unable to access any Stack Exchange site, or will shortly lose access once their local DNS caches expire.

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Yep, you were right.

Comment: It appears the nameservers are beginning to resolve properly now. So this will be a non-event shortly...

Comment: Seems like every stackexchange sites were down.. I happens sometimes (well if you are not google)

Comment: ServerFault stayed up for me, everything else was down. Perhaps I was just lucky and the DNS was still cached.

Comment: in case someone is curious, it lasted 38 min aprox (from 11:21 p.m to 11:59 p.m CST)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Things should be coming up again shortly. We recently relocated our NY datacenter, and therefore all the IPs in NY changed.

We didn't update to the new IP for the master DNS server (in both the named.conf and the zone files), and therefore all of our slaves hit our expiry time (one week). This is fixed now, so things should start coming back up.

We apologize for the oversight on our part.

Comment: Next time, don't forget to [tweet it](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) :) I always go there when SE is down to figure out when I ought to try again.

Comment: It has been tweeted